# Is there a good way to preventDefault when dispatching an action in React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm dispatching an action that runs a reducer that pushes some text to my redux state on form submit. I know in Vue you can `preventDefault` right in the DOM but I haven't seen anything in React that would make this seem possible.

I'm wondering the best way to prevent the form from submitting so Redux can do it's thing. My code is below. Thanks!

actions/index.js

```js
export function addLink(text) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_LINK',
        text
    }
}
```

reducers/index.js (ADD_LINK) is the function I'm running

```js
/*eslint-disable*/
export function linkList(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_LINK': 
            var text = action.text;
            console.log('Adding link');
            console.log(text);
            return {
                ...state,
                links: [text, ...state.links]
            };
        case 'DELETE_LINK':
            var index = action.index;
            console.log('Deleting link');
            return {
                ...state,
                links: [
                    ...state.links.slice(0, index),
                    ...state.links.slice(index + 1)
                ],
            };
        case 'UPDATE_LINK':
            var index = action.index;
            var newText = action.newText;
            console.log(action.newText);
            console.log(action.index);
            return {
                ...state,
                links: [ 
                    ...state.links.slice(0, index),
                    newText,
                    ...state.links.slice(index + 1)
                ],
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};

export default linkList;
```

components/LinkInput.js (Here is where I dispatch the action onSubmit)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LinkInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: '',
    };
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        text: e.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <form className="form form-inline" onSubmit={this.props.data.addLink.bind(null, this.state.text)} style={styles.form}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="label" htmlFor="exampleInputName2" style={styles.label}>Add a link: </label>
            <input type="text" className="input form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} style={styles.input}/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="button btn btn-primary" style={styles.button}>Add link</button>
        </form>
    );
  }
}
```

export default LinkInput;

Comment: The way you do it is the right way.

Comment: use your own handler on onSubmit and call addLink on that handler just after e.preventDefault().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What i would do is define a function in your component called `_onSubmit` and have it do like so:

```
_onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.data.addLink(this.state.text)
}
```

and then your form component just uses `this._onSubmit` for its `onSubmit` handler

`<form className="form form-inline" onSubmit={this._onSubmit} style={styles.form}>`

this will handle the event and dispatch the correct action.