# React: Adding event.preventDefault() Method Into Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I'm trying to avoid refreshing page by adding a `preventDefault()` call into the `onClick` handler of a functional component (`BookList` defined in bookList.js). I know I can make it with from class component to functional. However, is there any way to call `preventDefault()` in the `onClick` event handler in `BookList`?

Here is my sample code:

**BookListElement.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BookList from '../components/bookList';
import { deleteBook } from '../store/actions/projectActions';

const BookListElement = ({books, deleteBook}) => {
  if(!books.length) {
    return (
      <div>
        No Books
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {Array.isArray(books) ? books.map(book => {
        return (
          <BookList book={book} deleteBook={deleteBook} key={book._id} />
        );
      }): <h1>something wrong.</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    books: state.books
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    deleteBook: _id => {
      dispatch(deleteBook(_id));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BookListElement);
```

**bookList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const styles = {
  borderBottom: '2px solid #eee',
  background: '#fafafa',
  margin: '.75rem auto',
  padding: '.6rem 1rem',
  maxWidth: '500px',
  borderRadius: '7px'
};

const BookList = ({ book: { author, publication, publisher, _id }, deleteBook }) => {
  return (
        <form>
          <div className="collection-item" style={styles} key={_id}>
            <h2>{author}</h2>
            <p>{publication}</p>
            <p>{publisher}</p>
            <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" onClick={() => {deleteBook(_id)}}>
              <i className="large material-icons">delete_forever</i>
            </button>
         </div>
       </form>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

**action.js**

```
export const deleteBookSuccess = _id => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_BOOK,
    payload: {
      _id
    }
  }
};

export const deleteBook = _id => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.delete(`${apiUrl}/${_id}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(deleteBookSuccess(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};
```

**reducer.js**

```
case DELETE_BOOK:
      let afterDelete = state.filter(book => {
        return book._id !== action.payload._id
      });
      return afterDelete;
```

Comment: I think this answer does exactly what you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877194/2382428).

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want a button to trigger form submission, add `type="button"` attribute to the `button` element.

By default a `button` submits the form (has `type` set to `submit`).
Setting `type="button"` signifies that it has no default behavior.

```html
<form>
  <button type="button">type button doesn't trigger refresh</button>
  <button>no type triggers refresh</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing changed. Still needs to refresh.

Comment: @gilgamesh it's not possible that the button could have triggered page refresh. The problem must be somewhere else. Please post your code to glitch.com or codesandbox.io for inspection.

Answer (score 1):

The `preventDefault` method needs to be called on an `event`. However in the way you are setting up your `onClick` handler, the `event` is not passed to your handler.

Here is how you can fix this issue (in bookList.js):

```
import React from 'react';

const BookList = ({ book: { author, publication, publisher, _id }, deleteBook }) => {

  const handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    deleteBook(_id);
  }

  return (
        <form>
          <div>
            <h2>{author}</h2>
            <p>{publication}</p>
            <p>{publisher}</p>
            <button onClick={ handleClick }>
              <i>delete_forever</i>
            </button>
         </div>
       </form>
  );
};
```

So `onClick` will pass the `event` (by default) then just call `preventDefault` on that `event`, and then call `deleteBook`.

Comment: Still needs to refreshing page.

Comment: @gilgamesh do you mean the page is still refreshing? Can you edit your question and include the code for `deleteBook`?

Comment: added action and reducer.js

Comment: @gilgamesh thanks. So what is the problem now though? The page does not refresh and it should? And be refresh do you mean the usual HTTP refresh or like a rerender from React?

Comment: When I delete output data, firstly browser is refreshing and after deleting its data.

Comment: @gilgamesh hmm the browser shouldn't refresh with `event.preventDefault` in place. Try adding `<form onSubmit={ e => e.preventDefault() }>`  to replace `<form>`

Comment: @gilgamesh can you paste your `<button>` definition line here?

Comment: without onClick : <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button">
          <i className="large material-icons">delete_forever</i>
        </button>

Comment: @gilgamesh no but specifically i want to see how you define the `onClick`

Comment: onClick definition in button : onClick={() => {deleteBook(_id)}}

Comment: @gilgamesh You need to change that to how I have it defined: `onClick={ handleClick }`

Comment: I changed before when you defined but still doesn't work and actually it should be worked in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple illustration (component) where one click event triggers the reload, and the other doesn't. If this doesn't work for you, the problem is another place, meaning in a different component(pieces of code you haven't provided). I hope it helps, if not maybe it will help someone in the future **:)**

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.preventDefault = this.preventDefault.bind(this);
    this.dontPrevent = this.dontPrevent.bind(this);
  }
  
  // handler recieves the `e` event object
  dontPrevent() {
    alert('This page will reload :)');  
  }
  
  preventDefault(e) {
    alert('Page will NOT reload');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
 
  
  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.preventDefault}>
         <div>
          <h3>NO Reload Example</h3> 
          <p>
            <button>Submit</button>&nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
       </form>
       <hr/>
       <form>
         <div>
          <h3>Reload Example</h3> 
          <p>
            <button onClick={this.dontPrevent}>Submit</button>
          </p>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution but as I described above I want to make it in functional component instead class component.